# How to run dojo from my own server (apache)..?

Tags: dojo

I have downloaded dojo build, now I have an doubt, in the below example code, I am using "dojo.js.uncompressed.js" as a start of source file, is it right? Just I want to display a button in the web page. Which one is the start file? in dojo library.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html dir="ltr">

    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
        </style>
        <script src="../dojo/lib/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js"
        djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");

            dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
                // Create a button programmatically:
                var button = new dijit.form.Button({
                    label: "Click me!",
                    onClick: function() {
                        // Do something:
                        dojo.byId("result1").innerHTML += "Thank you! ";
                    }
                },
                "progButtonNode");

            });
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../dojo/lib/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"  />
    </head>

    <body class=" claro ">
        <button id="progButtonNode" type="button">
        </button>
        <div id="result1">
        </div>
        <!-- NOTE: the following script tag is not intended for usage in real
        world!! it is part of the CodeGlass and you should just remove it when
        you use the code -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.addOnLoad(function() {
                if (document.pub) {
                    document.pub();
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

dojo (and any js file) should be put next to your html files so that it is served by the server. Then you don't have to relate to long relative paths

Comment: Now the problem is I am not able to get output, dojo component is not loaded in to my browser. In simple internet examples, refer some website like ""http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js", So "dojo.xd.js" is a main file to start, when I run from my own server, which one is the start file?

Comment: @osdevkid When you're running it from your own server, dojo/dojo.js is the "main" file. The xd in dojo.xd.js means "cross domain".